# Which event do I use to react to a user checking an item in a ListView control (CF 3.5)?

Tags: vb.net, listview, compact-framework

When trying to use the ItemCheck event of a ListView, I have found that the event fires **before** the item is checked, so running code that looks to see which items are checked doesn't work as expected, because the item that's just been checked still has its old Checked value.

```
Private Sub MyListView_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles MyListView.ItemCheck
```

There's an ItemChecked event in .NET Framework, but alas, this is missing in .NET Compact Framework.  Is there some other way of executing code **after** a ListViewItem has been checked?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this event, as the arguments expose the items which was checked and its value through the  ItemCheckEventArgs.NewValue and ItemCheckEventArgs.Index properties.

You should be able to use this information, with the other items in your listview to determine the current state of the object.

Comment: The issue is that I'm not only interested in the item that's just been checked - I'm interested in **ALL** of the items that are checked in the ListView.  Unfortunately, if I look at the ListViewItems when the ItemCheck event is fired, the item that's just been checked or unchecked still has its old value, not the new one, because the event fires **before** the ListViewItem has been updated.

Comment: +1 Good answer, and it provided the OP with enough information to craft a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a few things and looking around the hidden events like MouseUp which don't seem to fire, I came up with this solution:

```
Private Sub MyListView_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles MyListView.ItemCheck
  Me.MyListView.Items(e.Index).Checked = CType(e.NewValue, Boolean)
  Call DoStuffWithCheckedItems()
End Sub
```

It seems to work quite reliably.  I'm basically just updating the Checked property myself.

Comment: The "normal" way to check which items are checked in a ListView is to get the list of checked items when you need them and not when an item is checked or unchecked by the user. So, you need and already found a workaround to implement code that does it the 'other' way. Using a framework you will always miss some basics in behind what really happens natively, viewed from a native win32 application.